# How to export a height map of my world map?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

In older versions of the game it wasn't particularly hard to export a height map of your world. However I can't seem to find any way to do so for the Steam version. I have designs of making an in game world map within my fort and I'd like to try and make it accurate across a couple of z-levels, but I can't figure out how to get the data.